# Hibernate Query Syntax Exception

Tags: hibernate

I'm getting the following hibernate query syntax exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected    
AST node: = near line 1, column 59 [SELECT u FROM     
com.vat.domain.entity.Employee u where (u.id = :id) <> 1]
```

Code:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>, 
JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee>  {

public final static String FIND_BY_Datatable_Filter = "SELECT u FROM 
Employee u where (u.id = :id) <> 1";

public final static String FIND_ALL_Active = "SELECT u FROM Employee u where 
u.status = 'Enabled' <> 1";

@Query(FIND_BY_Datatable_Filter)
public Page<Employee> findByDatatableFilter(@Param("id") int id, Pageable     
pageable);

@Query(FIND_ALL_Active)
public Page<Employee> findAllActiveEmployees(Pageable pageable);

}
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: `where (u.id = :id) <> 1` is invalid syntax what should it be? also here: `where 
u.status = 'Enabled' <> 1";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries are wrong.  `(u.id = :id) <> 1` is not valid sytax.

I think your queries must look like:

```
public final static String FIND_BY_Datatable_Filter = "SELECT u FROM 
Employee u where (u.id = :id)";

public final static String FIND_ALL_Active = "SELECT u FROM Employee u where 
u.status = 'Enabled'";
```

But it is not really clear for me what `<> 1` in this expression means.